# Is there different between this two ways of creating an object

Tags: java

I just have learned java. I'm fiding the different between this both ways of creating an object

```
public class A {
}
public class B extends A {
}
public static void main(String[] args){
       A object = new B();
       B object = new B();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets understand it with the example below.

1. In class A we added a getMethodofA(). So creating reference variable as A or B does not matter. As A is super class getMethodofA() will be available for both the objects of Type A or Type B
2. In class B we added a getMethodofB(). So creating reference variable as A or B matters. If you create object with reference variable as A, then only getMethodofA() will be available. While If you create object with reference variable B both the methods will be visible getMethodofA() and getMethodofB()

   ```
   public class A {

        public void getMethodofA(){
            System.out.println("I am method A")
        }

   }

   public class B extends A {
        public void getMethodofB(){
           System.out.println("I am method B")
       }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
       A objectA = new B();
       objectA.getMethodofA();//No error
       objectA.getMethodofB();//Compile time error

       B objectB = new B();
       objectB.getMethodofA();//No error
       objectB.getMethodofB();//No error
   }
   ```

Comment: This is a good example. Can you add some text (either of your own, or quoting from a tutorial, etc) with a citation that explains the example? While the actual rule that every B is an A, so we can call methods of A even when the declared type is B might be clear to us from experience, it may still be confusing to OP and other readers.